# I want to scrape these product information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://twillmkt.com'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://twillmkt.com/collections/denim')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tra = soup.find_all('div',class_='ProductItem__Wrapper')
productlinks=[]
Title=[]
Brand=[]
Colour=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True)[1:]:
        comp=baseurl+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)
for link in productlinks:
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    Title.append(title)
    price=soup.find('span',class_="money").text
    Brand.append(price)
    Product_Features=soup.find_all('li').text 
    Colour.append(Product_Features)
    

df = pd.DataFrame(
    
    {"Title": Title, "Price": Brand,"Product_Features":Colour}
)
print(df)
```

I scrape the title and price but difficult to scrape  these  information `SIZE`,`product feature`,`material`,`model size`,`image`
**Single Page Link**
https://twillmkt.com/products/light-blue-butterfly-print-slim-leg-denim?variant=39498848403534

Comment: I assume you should be able to do a search for the Materials text and parse it

Comment: you help me scrape these information I try to do parse but I cannot do these

Answer (score 0):

i'll give you the css selectors for the elements you want. you can catch them with `soup.select()`

size: `select[id^="product-select"] option`

product feature: `div.ProductMeta__Description.Rte li`

material: `div.ProductMeta__Description.Rte p:nth-of-type(2)`

model size: `div.ProductMeta__Description.Rte p:nth-of-type(3)`

image: `div[id^="Image"] span img`

Comment: ok I try that then tell you

Comment: when I written .text  (`div.ProductMeta__Description.Rte li`')`.text`   they give me error

Comment: `soup.select` produces lists of elements like `find_all`

Comment: can you modify my code and provide answer??

Comment: no i can't, your code says you know how to do it